# column doesn't exist in table whiel its showing the column in schema

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i am using postgresql .i am using psql.i run a command \d+ user i get schema of user table .
but when i run the command select first_name from user .its giving me error

```
ritesh=# select first_name from user;
ERROR:  column "first_name" does not exist
LINE 1: select first_name from user;
               ^
```

as you can see in the screenshot .How to resolve it  and where i am mistaking please explain.[image]

Comment: try "select first_name from public.user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try "select first_name from public.user"

Comment: ... and the reason this works, and the other didn't, is... ? This is a hackish way around the real problem that will just cause the poster more problems later.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth reasons.  It does clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs because ["user" is a keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). You should not use it for table names, etc. Otherwise you get fun like this.

See, `user` is a magic pseudo-function that returns the current username - it's an alias for `current_user`:

```
regress=> SELECT user;
 current_user 
--------------
 testuser
(1 row)
```

So what you're trying to do is call the function `user` in a set-returning context, and get the column `first_name` from it. The function result has no such column, hence the error.

Don't just schema-qualify your table as `public.user` to get around this. At minimum you should be using quoted identifiers if you're going to use SQL keywords for table names, e.g.:

```
select first_name from "user";
```

but really, it'll be much better to just name your table something that doesn't conflict with a keyword.